# How to expose the content formatter in a custom Eclipse editor?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jface

I am writing a custom Eclipse editor by subclassing `TextEditor`, and I can't use the `Format` action that I configured.

I read the 3 parts in [Creating a commercial quality IDE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-ecl-commplgin2/), and I know about `SourceViewerConfiguration`. I implemented the required method:

```
  override def getContentFormatter(viewer: ISourceViewer) = {
    val formatter = new MultiPassContentFormatter(getConfiguredDocumentPartitioning(viewer), IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE)
    formatter.setMasterStrategy(new ScalaFormattingStrategy(textEditor))
    formatter
  }
```

However, I can't find `Format` anywhere in the menu, contextual menu, toolbar, etc. The Java shortcut (`CMD-Shift-F`) does not work either.

Edit: I have implemented other methods in the `SourceViewerConfiguration` subclass I created, and everything else works as expected in my editor (completion, hyperlinking, reconciliation).

What is the preferred way to expose the formatter? Do I need to do anything more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [Eclipse formatter FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_support_formatting_in_my_editor%3F):

> Finally, you will need to **create an action** that invokes the formatter.
>   No generic formatting action is defined by the text infrastructure,
>   but it is quite easy to create one of your own. The action’s run
>   method can simply call the following on the source viewer to invoke
>   the formatter:
>
> `sourceViewer.doOperation(ISourceViewer.FORMAT);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link! I googled a lot but didn't find anything relevant. Looks good!